# The requested PHP extension ext-xsl * is missing from your system

Tags: php, magento2

Hi there I'm trying to install Magento 2, and i'm getting "The requested PHP extension ext-xsl * is missing from your system" please help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a general question about server configuration and better suited for serverfault.com

Comment: you can install it with 
sudo apt-get install php5-xsl

Comment: Just comment here as a reference for other people:
- sudo apt-get install php5-xsl (=> to install it)
- sudo php5enmod xsl (=> to enable xsl)
- sudo service apache2 restart (suppose you are using apache2, then need to restart it)

Answer (score 2):

This is not a Magento 2 related issue. It's a server configuration issue.
The php extension `xls` is required in order to make Magento 2 work.
See details about how to install/enable it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/xsl.installation.php)

Comment: I have no idea how to get this file

Comment: Modify PHP.ini
$vi/usr/local/php/etc/php.ini

Extension=xsl.so

Then restart the PHP service/etc/init.d/php-fpm restart

Go back to/home/wwwroot/magento2 and execute it again.